# Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.stripe.com:443

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, stripe-payments

Our servers are hosted on AWS EC2 Instance and we started receiving the following error today after the AWS Support changed somethings with DNS

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.stripe.com:443

{ Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe.
    at /var/www/html/Goeat/admin_and_store_panel/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:219:9
    at ClientRequest.req.on (/var/www/html/Goeat/admin_and_store_panel/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:474:67)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:401:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:73:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
  type: 'StripeConnectionError',
  raw:
   { message: 'An error occurred with our connection to Stripe.',
     detail:
      { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.stripe.com:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
        errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
        code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
        syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
        hostname: 'api.stripe.com',
        host: 'api.stripe.com',
        port: '443' } },
  rawType: undefined,
  code: undefined,
  doc_url: undefined,
  param: undefined,
  detail:
   { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.stripe.com:443
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
     errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
     code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'api.stripe.com',
     host: 'api.stripe.com',
     port: '443' },
  headers: undefined,
  requestId: undefined,
  statusCode: undefined,
  charge: undefined,
  decline_code: undefined,
  payment_intent: undefined,
  payment_method: undefined,
  setup_intent: undefined,
  source: undefined }
```

Could you please help us with the issue ?

Comment: "started receiving the following error today after the AWS Support changed somethings" I would suggest reaching out to AWS support in that case. Maybe they removed the ability to access external sites?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?